# Does Java implicitly check > and == when >= is run?

Tags: java, operators

When I use ">=" in a code, does Java automatically check "==" and ">"?

The reason I ask this question is because in a for loop like such:

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    if(a > b) //do something
    else if(a == b) //do something different
}
```

it be more efficient to do

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    if(a >= b){
        if(a > b) //do something
        else // do the thing you would do for a == b
    }
}
```

if a>=b does not check a==b and a>b separately.

The reason for this is because in the second for loop you check conditions 1 or 2 times while for the first for loop you always check conditions 2 time.

I realize that the time difference is negligible, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Java bytecode does have the instruction `if_icmpge` ("if int compare greater equal"). Not sure how the JVMs implement this.

Comment: I realized that my logic was wrong. Even if <= and < take the same time, they will be equally efficient assuming a and b are randomized. This is because if a<b, loop 1 checks twice, loop 1 checks once. If a == b, loop 1 checks twice, loop 2 checks twice If a>b, loop 1 checks once, loop 2 checks twice. So overall they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the most fundamental level a comparison is just a subtraction followed by a test of the result.  CPUs set flags after arithmetic operations: overflow and zero are the ones relevant to comparisons.  Overflow (ov) is set if the result is negative, and zero (z) is set if the operands were equal.  So `1 < 2` would translate to `(1 - 2)` resulting in ov:1 and z:0.

The desired combinations of flag values can be tested in a single operation:

- Less than : ov:1 and z:0
- Less or equal : ov:1 or z:1
- Equal : z:1
- Greater or equal : ov:0 or z:1
- Greater : ov:0 and z:0

So with a decent JVM implementation you will find that there is no detectable performance difference between `>` and `>=`

Answer (score 3):

The Java Virtual Machine [has separate instructions `if_icmpeq` (equal), `if_icmpge` (greater or equal), and `if_icmpgt` (greater than)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_icmp_cond) for the two cases. Whether it will be more efficient in fact depends on the CPU architecture; the x86 does have a single [`JGE` (jump if greater or equal)](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/jge) instruction.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer shows, it depends on the system architecture, but in general the general evaluation of greater or equal is two condition separed with "or" .
Even if we suppose that the comparaison will not do the two condition separatly, your reasoning still false. 
If we have in reality "a>b" 
For the first loop, we will compare 1 condition ">". 
For the second loop, we will compare 2 time, one for the first "non divisible >= " condition, and one for the ">" 
So the two loop are equivalent and it is better to choose according to the visibility you want and the utility you need. But the two are the same in average of comparisons.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that if a<b, then the second loop is checked once while the first is checked twice. On the other hand, if a<=b, the first loop considers either one/two times while the second loop always considers twice. Given that a and b are random values, the second loop will be more efficient. That is, of course, assuming that >= and > take the same time.

Comment: you taught just in the case of a<b but you should see in all cases